# How to set up a DNS name server to always resolve to a constant IP address for every request

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I am looking for a simple DNS name server set up to always return the same IP address no matter what the request is. The reason for this is we are a domain registrar and when a domain is first registered we need it to have valid name servers (and don't want to have to first create name server records before registering a domain). We will then subsequently change the name server records after the domain has been registered.

I assume this is possible to do with bind but was wondering if there might be a simpler solution available using one of the more light weight name servers out there? Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in a simple manner will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason for this is we are a domain registrar and when a domain is first registered we need it to have valid name servers [...] we will then subsequently change the name server records after the domain has been registered.

I'm not completely convinced you understand how this works.

Registering *nameservers* is registry side.
Adding the *DNS records* for a *nameserver* is your side of things, using BIND, as you have mentioned.

For nameservers to be valid, they do *not* need to resolve your IP address - they just need to be nameservers in the registry. You are free to register your domain using `nsxx.google.com`, just don't expect your website to work  anytime soon. If that is all your problem is - register it using whatever ones you have setup for your own website. Then create the child nameservers on the registered domain as normal, and go from there.

---

If your nameservers are already setup, you can just put this on your `named.conf`:

```
zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "path_to_default_zone_file";
};
```

and in the zone file, have an appropriate

```
* IN A 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Another way of putting it is I am looking for a catchall type of thing. So if my nameserver is ns1.mynameserver.com a request to resolve an A record for any domain will always return a certain IP address of say 1.2.3.4 (without any entries having been configured for that specific domain). This way I can point the IP address to a load balancer that always returns a page saying something like "This domain has been registered with myISP and is not yet active" or something like that. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes - but then the nameserver part of your question was a complete red herring, as now it's like you've got all that part sorted already :-) Please see my edits.